# Stacked Clustered Chart in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I create an Excel chart with stacked columns clustered with each other? Please see the picture to understand the exact requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is how to specify the data series, here is how I'd fill them. If you have other problems, please specify.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See this tutorial: [Clustered and Stacked Column and Bar Charts](http://peltiertech.com/clustered-stacked-column-bar-charts/)

See this forum to download an example Excel file: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-2007-help/720699-cluster-stacked-column-chart-excel-2007-a.html